# SimpleSAML configuration error, getting this error. What could be the issue?

Tags: simplesamlphp

When I load my **SimpleSAML** instance and try to authenticate using Google, I am getting following error:

```
"Debug information
The debug information below may be of interest to the administrator / help desk:

SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Backtrace:
0 /var/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:179 (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: Could not resolve 'authgoogle:Google': No class named 'sspmod_authgoogle_Auth_Source_Google'.
Backtrace:
6 /var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Module.php:134 (SimpleSAML_Module::resolveClass)
5 /var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:207 (SimpleSAML_Auth_Source::parseAuthSource)
4 /var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:247 (SimpleSAML_Auth_Source::getById)
3 /var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Default.php:59 (SimpleSAML_Auth_Default::initLogin)
2 /var/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:136 (SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple::login)
1 /var/simplesamlphp/modules/core/www/authenticate.php:45 (require)
0 /var/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:134 (N/A)"
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable SSP modules before you can use them.

```
touch [INSTALL_DIR]/modules/authgoogle/enable
```

If you create an `enable` file in the module directory then SSP's custom autoloader will load classes from that module.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the Google module was missing.

Comment: Looks like two modules were missing. 'authgoogleOIDC' 'authgoogle'

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, on the config file is a part where its overriding the enable and disable file, just add the authgoogle module and it will work

```
/***********
     | MODULES |
     ***********/

    /*
     * Configuration to override module enabling/disabling.
     *
     * Example:
     *
     * 'module.enable' => [
     *      'exampleauth' => true, // Setting to TRUE enables.
     *      'consent' => false, // Setting to FALSE disables.
     *      'core' => null, // Unset or NULL uses default.
     * ],
     *
     */

     'module.enable' => [
         'exampleauth' => true,
         'core' => true,
         'saml' => true,
         'authgoogle' => true
     ],
```